# Use parametrized values with Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm working with an Azure LogicApp where the workflow have fixed values. Our DevOps tool is VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) and because we have multiple environments to handle, I have to do some refactoring (using parametrized values) so in VSTS we'll be able to provide environment-specific values.

Thanks to 2 websites I found on Internet I managed to understand that there are 3 kind of parameters :

[image]
To understand my problem, here's my action :

[image]
I want to have my string "/work/documents" in a parameter value. So in the "Code view" I managed to use a parameter instead of a hard-coded value :

```
          "triggers": {
        "When_a_file_is_added_or_modified": {
          "type": "ApiConnection",
          "inputs": {
            "host": {
              "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sftp_1']['connectionId']"
              }
            },
            "method": "get",
            "path": "/datasets/default/triggers/onupdatedfile",
            "queries": {
              "folderId": "@{parameters('pathToRootFolder')}"
            }
          },
          "recurrence": {
            "frequency": "Hour",
            "interval": 1
          }
        }
      }
```

And in my parameters.json :

```
    "sftp_1_path_root_folder": {
        "value": "/work/documents"
    }
```

Here's the final result in Visual Studio:

[image]

Am I missing something ? Why isn't the value displayed in the Designer ? Thank you for your help in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using Logic Apps parameters inside your Logic App definition, they are not resolved at design-time, but at run-time. Thus, you are not supposed to see them in the designer. If you run the workflow, you should be able to see the actual value at run-time.

If you want to resolve those parameters at deployment-time, then you would need to write directly from the ARM template using ARM parameters into the workflow definition. This is possible, but in some cases, it can become a bit more complex. That's why I prefer to make use of Logic Apps parameters as described [here](https://blog.mexia.com.au/preparing-azure-logic-apps-for-cicd).

Comment: You know what ? That's exactly one of the 2 websites I used :D Nice article BTW ;-D

Comment: The link mentioned in the answer is inaccessible. Check the archive version of it: [Preparing Azure Logic Apps for CI/CD using ARM Templates](https://web.archive.org/web/20180407202503/https://blog.mexia.com.au/preparing-azure-logic-apps-for-cicd)